# apt-get - select the oldest google-chrome file in sources.list.d

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, google-chrome, repository

In the folder `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` I have the file:

google-chrome-repo.list:

```
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/google-chrome-keyring.gpg] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
deb-src [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/google-chrome-keyring.gpg] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

and in the folder `/usr/share/keyrings` i have a file named `google-chrome-keyring.gpg`

If I install google-chrome:

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

That annoying second file is created in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` with the name `google-chrome.list`, with content:

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

and the file in the `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d` folder named `google-chrome.gpg`

If I don't delete the annoying autogenerated file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`, then the command:

```
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
```

will give the following error:

```
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable: /usr/share/keyrings/google-chrome-keyring.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

My goal instead is to be able to do `apt-get install` and `apt-get purge` of google-chrome as many times as I want, without first having to delete the autogenerated file each time.

How can i get this?
Is there a way to make `apt-get` ignore that file?

The solutions proposed in other topics like `delete that file` are not really functional.

I want to be able to use `apt-get` directly as written above and not scripts or substitute functions.

It would be nice if there were some `Dpkg::Options::=` like:

`Of multiple coincident files in "sources.list.d", only consider the oldest one (the one created first).`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think what you explicitly asks is possible (to use only the oldest source file).

But instead, you can make a `DPkg::Post-Invoke` command that runs after using `apt`/`dpkg` to remove the file you don't want.

Create the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/100post-invoke` (you can call it anything you like) with the contents:

```
# This is a list of shell commands to run after invoking dpkg/apt-get #
DPkg::Post-Invoke { "rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list"; };
```

Now, after running any `apt install` or `apt purge` command, the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` will be deleted (or ignored if it doesn't exist).

You can of course add any number of commands to the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/100post-invoke` file to customize the behavior of `apt`/`dpkg`.

Comment: Ok, is an acceptable answer

Comment: Sounds good - I believe this is closest to what you want to do. 